# Using Linq to Select properties of class to return IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

If I have a `SortedList<int, MyClass>` and I want to return a new `IEnumerable<T>` of properties from that class how do I do that?

I have tried `SortedList.Select(x=>x.MyProperty, x.AnotherProperty)` but it doesnt work.

Thanks.

Comment: How should the "Enumerable of properties" present itself? Could you give us a sample, preferably with pseudo-code?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could return an anonymous object:

```
var result = SortedList.Select(x => new { 
    x.Value.MyProperty, 
    x.Value.AnotherProperty 
});
```

Or if you want to use the result outside of the scope of the current method you could define a custom type:

```
IEnumerable<MyType> result = SortedList.Select(x => new MyType { 
    Prop1 = x.Value.MyProperty, 
    Prop2 = x.Value.AnotherProperty 
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Was having a bang head against wall moment and forgot the x => new {.......