# Error with SortedList: "Does not contain a definition for Select."

Tags: c#, linq

The following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850812/using-linq-to-select-properties-of-class-to-return-ienumerablet) suggests using this syntax:

```
var result = SortedList.Select(x => new { 
    x.Value.MyProperty, 
    x.Value.AnotherProperty 
});
```

However, when I attempt to test it, I receive the error:

> *`System.Collections.SortedList` does not contain a definition for `Select`.*

I have the following references:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.IO;
```

Despite extensive Internet searching, I cannot figure out how to fix this. Can anyone help?

**EDIT:**
perhaps I am going about this wrong. my goal is to return a subset of a SortedList as a SortedList.

```
var subset = data.Where(x => x.Key >= startDate && x.Key <= endDate);
```

where 'data' is a

```
SortedList<DateTime, BarData>
```

'barData' is a class

Comment: Make sure you have System.Core.dll other than that, "SortedList" needs to be an instance variable -- not sure what you are using since "SortedList" is pascal case in your example.

Comment: Have you tried using System.Collections.Generic.SortedList instead?

Comment: I was getting the same error "does not contain a definition for Select" for a custom dictionary.  I never found a straight-forward reason for the error, as I had all the right namespaces and dlls.  But the problem did go away when I stopped using my own custom KeyValuePair class and just used the standard one.  I suspect the problem had something to do with my class implementing both IEnumerable<CustomerKeyValuePair> and IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note:** I'm posting this as a completely new answer because the recent edit to your question has made it clear that the real problem is quite different from what it first seemed.

1. Select the subset from `data` that you want in your resulting `SortedList<…>`:

   ```
   var subset = data.Where(x => x.Key >= startDate && x.Key <= endDate);
   ```
2. Build a new `SortedList` from the filtered items:

   ```
   var sortedListSubset = new SortedList<DateTime, BarData>();

   foreach (var subsetItem in subset)
   {
       sortedListSubset.Add(subsetItem.Key, subsetItem.Value);
   }
   ```

   I don't see an easier solution. The problem is that `Enumerable.Where` will return an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime, BarData>>`, and there's no extension method to convert that back to a `SortedList<…>`. Thus the need to iterate through the `IEnumerable<…>` item by item and add them to a fresh `SortedList<…>`.

> **When to use `Where` and when to use `Select`:**
>
> - Use `Where` whenever you want to find a subset, ie. when you want to "filter" a collection. (If you know SQL well, `Where` corresponds to `WHERE`, hence the name.)
> - Use `Select` when you want to change/transform, or "project", each element of a collection into something else. In functional programming, this operation is often called "map". (Again, if you know SQL well, then `Select` — unsurprisingly — corresponds to `SELECT`.)
>
> Finally, remember that instead of `data.Where(x => x.Key >= …)`, you could have written:
>
> ```
>  var subset = from x in data 
>               where x.Key >= … 
>               select x
> ```
>
> This is some syntactic sugar that C# allows, but essentially means the same thing (however in this form, the `select` cannot be omitted, even if it doesn't really do any projection). Note again the similarity to SQL!

Comment: thank you stakx.  i was hoping for a less verbose solution, but have implemented your suggestion.  also, i appreciate the detailed explanation and advice on Where vs. Select.

Comment: @Ben, you're welcome. Btw.: If you find that a given answer has been helpful, you can click the up-arrow symbol next to it. If an answer has solved your problem, you can check the tick mark next to it. (That will signal to others that your question has already been "answered".) [See also the FAQ "How do I ask questions here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 3):

> **Note:** You've recently edited your question, stating the real issue, which probably renders this answer obsolete. I've posted a new one to address the "real" issue.

---

1. Make sure your project has a reference to `System.Core.dll`. That's the .NET assembly which contains LINQ's extension methods for just about any collection type.

   (This includes `Select` which you couldn't find with `SortedList`. `Select` is actually a static method found in the static class [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx).)
2. Make sure you have at least the following two `using` directives (you already do):

   ```
   using System.Collections;  // makes referring to SortedList easier
   using System.Linq;         // required for the Select method
   ```
3. Since `SortedList` is a non-generic and untyped collection, ie. it contains only `object`s, in order to use LINQ's `Select` method and/or access the elements' `Value` property, **you first need to invoke LINQ's `Cast<T>` operator**. Try this:

   ```
   var result = sortedList.Cast<TItem>().Select(x => new { 
       x.Value.MyProperty, 
       x.Value.AnotherProperty 
   });
   ```

   where `TItem` is the name of the type of the items in your `SortedList`.

**P.S.:** I'm assuming that `SortedList` in your example refers to a local variable, or field, or property, and is not used as the type name. That's why I changed the capitalization to `sortedList`.

**P.P.S.:** Unless you have a good reason not to, life might be a little easier if you used the [`System.Collections.Generic.SortedList<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) class, as some others here have already suggested before me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using SortedList as a static class, or your object is named the same as the class. Anyway, this should work:

```
var myList = new SortedList<int, int>();
var mySelect = myList.Select(x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The LINQ Select method is receives an IEnumerable. But SortedList doesn´t implement this interface.

Comment: IF you use System.Collections.Generic.SortedList<TSource> you´ll have that all LINQ methods.